# How to install visual studio code on linux?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6.5

I'm install Visual studio code in Linux centos 6.5 But I got some error because that code required any library but I don't know how to find it

Here is the errore code

```
code: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by code)
code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by code)
code: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /root/my project/VSCode-linux-x64/libnode.so)
code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/my project/VSCode-linux-x64/libnode.so)
code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /root/my project/VSCode-linux-x64/libgcrypt.so.11)
code: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /root/my project/VSCode-linux-x64/libgcrypt.so.11)
```

Please help to tell me how can I get all the missing library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 6 uses glibc 2.12, while Visual Studio Code requires v2.14 at the minimum.  I doubt you'll get it running on that platform, as you can't just install a newer version of glibc - it's *the* most fundamental library and replacing it might not be impossible in theory, but in practice, using a system with a more modern version (e.g. CentOS 7) will be *much* easier.